# I want to add liquidity into Raydium programmatically

Tags: anchor, solana-program, spl-token, liquiditypool, dex

I have developed a presale smart contract using Anchor, and it is currently functional. Now, I am exploring ways to transition to a public sale on decentralized exchanges (DEX) like Raydium after completing the presale. However, I am facing challenges in finding the appropriate steps to achieve this. I hope the community can provide assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Waiting for the reply too, there is too much parameters to pass I need clarity on how and where to find them

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [deposit](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions/blob/8710befa6d900a15b03a2fadb8a7caa0a91cfbdb/lib/src/amm_instruction.rs#L140) instruction by calling [this](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions/blob/8710befa6d900a15b03a2fadb8a7caa0a91cfbdb/lib/src/amm_instruction.rs#L551) function from raydium-io's `raydium-contract-instructions` package.

[Here](https://github.com/0xcrust/raydium-swap.git) is is an example of a program that interacts with the raydium program. Although it calls a different instruction from what you want, you can use it as a reference point.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But there are still some difficulties to understand deposit function. I have to call deposit function from my program directly with CPI and relevant accounts ? How deposit function works exactly? Hope you to explain in more detail. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide some docs or code snippet to understand this process?

Answer (score 0):

There are demo functions for adding liquidity to CPMM and CLMM pool in the demo-sdk.

https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/ammAddLiquidity.ts
https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/clmmCreatePosition.ts

To run these functions you'll need to set your keys and rpc in the config files.

A simple edit of the above should be suffisant to perform the action describe above.

Give a look at the README.md

/ withdraw functions are also available in the demo-sdk

Comment: I already checked all related documentation, but couldn`t find the suitable answer.